# Left outer join with eagar loading

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, left-join, extension-methods

I am writing a linq having a left outer join with conditions on right side table.
my code

```
 var leftHotelRooms = db.HotelRooms.Include(hr=>hr.HotelRoomBlackoutPeriods)
                    .Where(room => hotelCodes.Contains(room.UserHotelId) &&
                      room.Scope == scope &&
                      room.IsDeleted == false &&
                      room.IsEnabled == true &&
                      room.MaxCapacity >= minimumNumberOfGuests)
                    .GroupJoin(db.HotelRoomBlackoutPeriods,
                              room => room.Id,
                              blackoutPeriod => blackoutPeriod.HotelRoomId,
                              (room, blackoutPeriod) => new
                              {
                                 room,
                                 blackoutPeriods = blackoutPeriod.DefaultIfEmpty()
                               })
                    .Select(a => new {a.room,a.blackoutPeriods})
                    .Where(
                           x => x.blackoutPeriods.Any(y => DbFunctions.DiffDays(y.StartDate, checkIn) != 0
                    &&    (DbFunctions.DiffDays(y.StartDate, checkIn) < 0) ? (DbFunctions.DiffDays(y.StartDate, checkOut) >= 0 ? false : true) : true &&
                        (DbFunctions.DiffDays(y.StartDate, checkIn) > 0) ?  (DbFunctions.DiffDays(y.EndDate, checkIn) <= 0 ? false : true) : true
                    ))
                    .ToList();
                }
```

which works perfectly fine but it **does not eagerly load**, when i convert result of above query to my business model it again fires some queries on `db.HotelRoomBlackoutPeriods`

Please provide the optimum way to achieve this.
thanks in advance. 
sorry (if i am asking something nonsense ) in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eager loading does not work when you change the shape of the result set. Shape of your result set is `HotelRoom` type. Once you use any manual join or projection, you are changing the result set and eager loading request is ignored.